# How to keep the background DIV appear desptie scrolling vertically

Tags: css, google-maps, html

I have two DIVs (one in back and another on font of it). Where the background Div shows a Google Maps and it fills the screen exactly (width=100% and height=100%) .
But the foreground DIV, it's height is much larger .

How to allow vertical scrolling for the foreground DIV with keeping the Google maps it's location fixed despite scroll vertically ?

[sample of what I want](http://livingsocial.com/deals/148163-seven-nights-at-baumanburi-resort-for-the-family)

as you see. the image in the background is fixed despite scrolling vertically

Comment: I updated the example to include a background image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merely wrap the map in a fixed container.

```
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    #map-wrapper,#maps{ width:100%; height:100%; }
    #map-wrapper{ position:fixed; }
    #article{
      position:absolute; width:50%; height:200%; 
      margin:0 0 20px -25%;
      background:#000 url(http://placekitten.com/1500/1000) center center no-repeat;
      text-align:center; overflow:hidden;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map-wrapper">
    <div id="maps"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="article"></div>
</body>
```

Tested in latest versions of Chrome, FF, Opera and Safari on Mac OSX.

Found the answer here:
http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-api/browse_thread/thread/33a3ed4d8cb6ba04?pli=1

However the problem of the map being zoomed in and out when the user hovers the "background" still remains.

Good luck! :)

Comment: exactly what I am seeking . but I don't understand the new problem :D

Comment: Depends on your implementation of Google maps. But if I just grab the plain code from here: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html and input it into the above example. Whenever my mouse is over the "foreground" I indeed scroll the whole page, but whenever my mouse is on the "background" do not scroll the page but rather zoom the map.

Comment: do you mean scrolling using the wheel ?!

Comment: Sorry about the ambiguity, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Use fixed positioning

example

http://jsfiddle.net/aysXW/4/

html:

```
<div id="fg">
this is the foreground
</div>

<div id="bg">
123 ... this is the background
</div>
```

css:

```
div#fg{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 1000px;
    left: 25%;
    width: 50%;
    color: white;
    border: green 5px solid;
}

div#bg{
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
z-index: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: url('http://img2.socwall.com/Nature/General/200717041506-1877.jpg') no-repeat blue;
}
```

I hope this helps

You don't have to define the height in pixels or the width, I just used it as an example.

Comment: Can I make the position of the background is fixed and absolute at the same time ?

Comment: The new problrm is .. when I set the position of DIV that represents Google maps V3.0 to "fixed".. the don't appear any more.. when I set the position to "absolute" it appeared , why ?!

Comment: Could you share a link? What we can do is have it absolute and move it with the scrollbar using jQuery but I'd like to see it first.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to add `background-attachment:scroll` to the `<div>` that has the background image on it.

Comment: In fact I have DIV that shows google maps. I tried what you have posted , but it didin't help :(

Answer (score -1):

I hope following css might help you:

```
body { 
    background-image: url('smiley.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center; 
}
```

[**Reference**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background-position)